# In Pose Mode Bones stoped rotate command

Tags: pose-mode

In my animation project everything was going smoothly but I dont know what but I think I did something and bones stoped responding rotate commands like (R Y).

I am frustrated because I can not find the reason.

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be partial answer for who had similar problem.

I did "A" Copy.

"File" new "General"

"A" "X" Confirm

Paste

In this new file everything started to work as they should be working.